# Using Microsoft Bot Framework,is it possible to combine multiple waterfalls into a function?

Tags: node.js, botframework, waterfall

I have developed a utility function to get userInformation(to check if the user is logged in) which uses three functions in a waterfall.The first function(**promptUserId**) silently sends a message to the UI and expects a response.The second functions saves the response(**saveUserId**) from UI and the third function(**processUserId **) processes the response from UI and returns a value.Is it possible to combine these 3 functions into one single function so that this utility can be used as a one line call wherever I want?

userUtil.js is the utility implemented and file1.js is the file using userUtil.js

Given below is userUtil.js

```
const promptUserId= (session, args, next) => {
        builder.Prompts.text(session, 'Ask UserId');
        next();
};

const saveUserId= (session, results, next) => {
    if (results.response){  
        session.dialogData.loginUserId = results.response;
    }else{
    session.dialogData.loginUserId ='XYZ12333333333';
    }
    next();
};


const processUserId = (userId) => {
    let userInfo,userObject;
    //process the received userId to get 'userObject' and assign it to userInfo 
   //userObject = result from api where input is userId and output is userObject    
    userInfo=userId;
    return userInfo;
};

module.exports = {
    promptUserId,
    saveUserId,
    processUserId
};
```

Here is file.js

```
const userUtil = require('../util/userUtil');

module.exports = [
    (session, args, next) => {
        userUtil.promptUserId(session, args, next);
    },

    (session, results, next) => {
        user.saveUserId(session, results, next);
    },

    async (session, args, next) => {
        session.dialogData.userInfo = await user.processUserId(session.dialogData.loginUserId);
        // user is logged in save consent and connect to agent
        if (session.dialogData.userData) {
            return session.dialogData.userData;
        }

    }
];
```

Is there a way to handle builder prompts in the single waterfall or to implement a function which returns return session.dialogData.userData ??

Comment: Were you able to get this working with my answer? If so, please "accept" and upvote it so others can quickly find the answer and I can clear this from my support tracker. If not, let me know how else I can help!

Answer (score 1):

You can combine them into a dialog similar to [this sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/v3-sdk-samples/Node/core-basicMultiDialog/bot.js#L104).

That being said, if this is a newer bot, **I highly recommend not building it in v3. Use [Bot Framework v4](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-js), instead.** Even if this isn't a newer bot, I recommend [migrating to v4](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/migration/migration-overview?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp). One major benefit that you'll get is the use of [Waterfall Dialogs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-dialog-manage-conversation-flow?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp), which can easily accomplish what you want.